# Ubuntu 18.04 Postfix. Email fails DNS lookup on the SMTP hosts

Tags: 18.04, postfix

I've installed and configured Postfix. It is sending email fine.

I reboot the server and email fails DNS lookup on the SMTP hosts. Repeatable via reboot.

If I restart the service all works fine until the next reboot.

I fear Postfix is starting before another network service is ready maybe? Any hints on how to fix?

```
Oct 22 12:40:12 homer postfix/cleanup[1346]: 848E9E60F89: message-id=<20181022124012.848E9E60F89@homer.the-corbins.net>
Oct 22 12:40:12 homer postfix/qmgr[1336]: 848E9E60F89: from=<root@homer>, size=363, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
Oct 22 12:40:12 homer postfix/smtp[2234]: 848E9E60F89: to=<johnj@outlook.com>, relay=none, delay=0.02, delays=0.02/0/0/0, dsn=4.4.3, status=deferred (Host or domain name not found. Name service error for name=smtp.gmail.com type=AAAA: Host not found, try again)
```

Comment: Are you on a ipv6 network? the DNS request seems to be an ipv6 record, here could be a solution : https://serverfault.com/a/577300/430340

Answer (score 0):

So I believe this is due to an interesting behavior postfix has where by default it puts itself into a chroot for greater security isolation. However, in doing so it copies the `/etc/resolv.conf` file into that chroot. So if that file changes on the host itself it'll fail to get updated within postfix, which means that if the DNS servers that you used to use are no longer accessible, then postfix will fail to look up DNS entries and therefore fail to send emails if it needs to relay emails on to a domain (or `smtp.gmail.com` in this case).

This only happens with certain configurations, and with the `resolvconf` package for instance this shouldn't happen as `postfix` will install hooks into `resolvconf` so that when it updates the DNS settings it reloads postfix too. To fix this you'll need to figure out what is updating your `/etc/resolv.conf` and make it go and restart postfix too.